# Python, issue with unescaping special HTML character in string variable obtained in a different way

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm new to Python and I'm asking for help to understand the problem with unescaping/print etc. the special HTML character in a string variable. As an example. String contains a special character `\x2d` to be replaced with a `-`.

Sample script that works:

```
import re
from html import unescape   # python 3.4+

def processLine(index, row):
    print(index, unescape(row))

testList = ["Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release snapd[1259]: overlord.go:268: Acquired state lock file", "Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully.", "Aug 11 20:38:27 uls2204-release systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000."]
testString = "Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully."

for idx, element in enumerate(testList, start = 1):
    if element == testString:
        print("True")
    processLine(idx, element)
```

In this example, the element[1] of the `testList` contains a character `-` as a HTML character `\x2d` twice. The script prints all the elements of the list as I need:

```
1 Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release snapd[1259]: overlord.go:268: Acquired state lock file
True
2 Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck-mountpoint-297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully.
3 Aug 11 20:38:27 uls2204-release systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
```

But if i change the script and create a string variable from the lines of the text file (line by line read) the replacement is not done. Modified script:

```
import re
from html import unescape   # python 3.4+

def processLine(index, row):
    print(index, unescape(row))

testList = ["Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release snapd[1259]: overlord.go:268: Acquired state lock file", "Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully.", "Aug 11 20:38:27 uls2204-release systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000."]
testString = "Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully."

logSource = 'file.in'

idx = 1
with open(logSource, 'rt', encoding = 'utf-8') as logInput:
    while (line := logInput.readline().strip()):
        if line == testString:
            print("True")
        processLine(idx, line)
        idx += 1
```

The modified script prints the following output:

```
1 Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release snapd[1259]: overlord.go:268: Acquired state lock file
2 Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully.
3 Aug 11 20:38:27 uls2204-release systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
```

Overwriting HTML code `\x2d` to character `-` is not performed in the output line #2.
Input file `file.in` content is:

```
$ cat file.in
Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release snapd[1259]: overlord.go:268: Acquired state lock file
Aug 11 20:34:56 uls2204-release systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 11 20:38:27 uls2204-release systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
```

Python version is:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

Please help me understand what is the reason and what I am doing wrong. I need to rewrite all HTML codes to characters before final processing of the file lines.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it just because on the end of line in your file.in you have special character of line break (\n)

Comment: @JamesRisner, i'm haven't enough reputation to post comments, but trying to help this mate(((

Comment: Yes. Every line in file.in have a '\n', but i delete line ends when I start loop: `while (line := logInput.readline().strip()):`

Comment: @AlexMaryenko, ok, then it because of autoescaping of \ when reading file. \x2b turns into \\x2b and later not equals.

Comment: Daniel, most likely yes, but I don't know how to see the line after reading from the file :( print() only shows `mp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d297125419.mount:` with one backslash. Now I temporarily, to avoid an error, convert the string to raw string and get a string with two backslash, like `mp-syscheck\\x2dmountpoint\\x2d297125419.mount:`. I don't have an error, but this is not the result I wanted - replacing `\x2d` with a `-` minus.

Comment: I also think that the unescape() does not work if I use a string variable, and do not read from a file, and in the first example print() performs the replacement... Now I'm trying to figure out which option of hex code the unescape() function converts `\x2d` or `&#x2D;`